# PDF Reading using PDF box - Clarification with page count

Tags: java, pdfbox, pdf-reader

Read a pdf file from url with using of PDFbox, below jave code its perfect to read a pdf and stored in project location.

```
String pdfPageCount = 17;
String pdfUrl = "abc.org/invoicepdf.pdf?Range=1";
URL pdfDownload = new URL(pdfUrl);
connectionGet = (HttpsURLConnection) pdfDownload.openConnection();
String authorizationHeader1 = "Bearer " + getToken;
connectionGet.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationHeader1);
connectionGet.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
connectionGet.setRequestMethod("GET");
int responseCode = connectionGet.getResponseCode();
    if (responseCode != 404) {
        PDDocument pd = new PDDocument();
        InputStream inputstreamFinal1 = connectionGet.getInputStream();
        PDDocument load = PDDocument.load(inputstreamFinal1);                        
        load.save("CopyOfInvoice1.pdf");
    }
```

My next step

I want to looping the process based on the `pdfPageCount` value, currently i do hard-coded the page count in 1 in the pdfUrl (`/invoicepdf.pdf?Range=1`)

Expected:

Read all the 17 pages and save into an single pdf file

Comment: so, you want to know how to combine 17 separate pdf pages into one document?

Comment: @rabbitguy: exactly

Comment: Apache provide a merger example in their examples: https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/util/PDFMergerExample.java?revision=1741693&view=markup

Comment: @TilmanHausherr IMO there is hardly more to say except probably providing the code... ;)

Comment: @Prabu As an aside, have you checked whether the web service can also provides the 17 pages in one go? The parameter name `Range` in the URL suggests that one might also use something like `/invoicepdf.pdf?Range=1-17` to retrieve a PDF of the first 17 pages...

Comment: @mkl: not possible to get 17 pages in single , we need to get one by one

Comment: What if you don't use the range at all? `/invoicepdf.pdf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code, based on the PDFMergerExample that is mentioned in the comments. Note that I haven't checked if your URL retrieval code is correct.

```
List<InputStream> sources = new ArrayList<InputStream>();
int pdfPageCount = 17;
try
{
    for (int p = 1; p <= pdfPageCount; ++p)
    {
        String pdfUrl = "abc.org/invoicepdf.pdf?Range=" + p;
        URL pdfDownload = new URL(pdfUrl);
        HttpsURLConnection connectionGet = (HttpsURLConnection) pdfDownload.openConnection();
        String authorizationHeader1 = "Bearer " + getToken;
        connectionGet.setRequestProperty("Authorization", authorizationHeader1);
        connectionGet.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        connectionGet.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = connectionGet.getResponseCode();
        if (responseCode != 404)
        {
            sources.add(connectionGet.getInputStream());
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO error handling
            return;
        }
    }
    PDFMergerUtility pdfMerger = new PDFMergerUtility();
    pdfMerger.addSources(sources);
    pdfMerger.setDestinationFileName("CopyOfInvoice1.pdf");
    pdfMerger.mergeDocuments(MemoryUsageSetting.setupMainMemoryOnly());
}
catch (IOException e)
{
     //TODO error handling
     return;
}
finally
{
    // cleanup
    for (InputStream source : sources)
    {
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(source);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but i have an issue in the finally section, its not clear properly the sources list , when i executed the first time count will be 2 and second time execution appended with new page count, so the document was not created

Comment: @Prabu I don't understand what you mean; could it be that you didn't initialize/empty the sources ArrayList the second time? (You cannot reuse it, because the input streams will be "consumed")